# linux script - substring and append compatibility with unix

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to make my following script compatible with other platforms (unix) and i am not sure if it will be. Especially [[test]] and %%# symbols are compatible. At lease this script works fine on linux.

It would be great if someone (who is familiar with unix) can make some suggestions or fixes to make the following script portable across the platforms (except windows).

```
#!/bin/sh


INSTALL_HOME=/opt/prod/install0308
export INSTALL_HOME

export CONF_INSTALL_ARGS="-Dinstall.ext.dir=/opt/prod/installExt -Dinstall.alternateExtDir=/opt/dev/installExt/lib -Dinstall.type=OSD"



INSTALL_ALTERNATIVE_TYPES_DIR=''

if [[ ${CONF_INSTALL_ARGS} == *'-Dinstall.alternateExtDir'* ]]; then
    INSTALL_ALT_TYPE_DIR_TEMP=${CONF_INSTALL_ARGS#*-Dinstall.alternateExtDir=}
    INSTALL_TYPE_DIR=${INSTALL_ALT_TYPE_DIR_TEMP%%-D*}
    FINAL_INST_TYPE_DIR="$(echo -e "${INSTALL_TYPE_DIR}" | sed 's/ *$//g')"
    INSTALL_ALTERNATIVE_TYPES_DIR=','$FINAL_INST_TYPE_DIR
fi

TOTAL_CONF_ARGS="-Dinstall.ext.dir=${INSTALL_HOME}/lib/provider,${INSTALL_HOME}/lib/security${INSTALL_ALTERNATIVE_TYPES_DIR}"

echo $TOTAL_CONF_ARGS
```

Comment: This isn't compatible even with Linux. Your script begins with `#!/bin/sh`, which would either run a POSIX shell or run bash in POSIX compatibility mode, and your conditions use `[[ ... ]]`, a bash-ism that is not part of POSIX.  The parameter expansion - `%%` and `#` should be fine (these are pretty universal). Have a look at [the man page for sh](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh) on other platforms to see what kinds of things are available. And test your script at http://shellcheck.net/.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a compatibility problem between Operating Systems, this is a compatibility problem between `Shells`.

Your script has been written for bash-like shells, so you just need to replace the first line `#!/bin/sh` by `#!/bin/bash` (or any path where `bash` is located) for it to work on other systems (do not forget to install `bash` on them).

NB: This script works on your Linux with the shebang `#!/bin/sh` probably because your Linux distribution has chosen to replace legacy `sh` by a link to `bash` or you are explicitly running the script with bash like this: `bash ./script.sh`.